# Объясните почему так?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```js
function f() {
  console.log(this.name);
}


f = f.bind({name: "Петя"}).bind({name:'Иван'});


console.log(f());
```

Объясните почему здесь `f = f.bind( {name: "Петя"} ).bind({name:'qwe'});` функция дополнительно не привязывается ? Почему выводится  'Петя'  если контекст другой уже?

Comment: Не надо ставить ненужные теги, особенно те, которым вообще нет описания. `this` есть не только в JS и не везде он работает одинаково

Comment: "если контекст другой уже" - нет не другой. Нельзя переписать контекст, который установили в первый раз

Comment: Смысл `.bind` ровно в том, что бы «навсегда» привязать конетекст. Так что его нельзя изменить при вызове функции из другого контекста или последующих вызовах bind